# Issues with SharedObject?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So, simply put, I am trying to use the SharedObject to simply hang onto a variable for me that I need to save for the user to remember an option choice. Nothing dramatic, but for some reason, no matter what I do, I cannot seem to actually create the SharedObject to interact with it in the following lines, I am running traces every step to just keep an eye out for where it is breaking, and the OBJ SET trace will run, but if I try to access the SortObject in anyway through .data, it just seems to not work? This is my first time messing with SharedObjects, and I am still pretty new to AS3 and since its an ailing platform to begin with, I cannot seem to find any reason for this to be failing? Every use of the 100 uses I have seen in action seem to use it in the same manner I do?

I am not throwing any compile errors as a result either.

From what I can tell, the SharedObject is simply not being created for some reason.

```
 public function ChangeSortSetting(event:Event) : *
    {

      var SortTypeSetting = event.target.name == "SortTypeSet";
      var ExtraSetting = event.target.name == "ExtraSet";

      trace(" VAR SET ")

      var SortObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("SortObject")

      trace(" OBJ SET? ")

      if (SortObject.data.SortMethod == null) 
        {
           SortObject.data.SortMethod = "alpha"
           SortObject.flush()
        }

      trace(" / 1UIX / OBJ TRACE CHECK / " + SortObject.data.SortMethod)
}
```

Comment: So, how do you actually check, if that stored variable is actually set? Also, keep in mind that if you write SO data from one SWF and then read it from another - it won't work like that.

Comment: Does your `SortObject.data.SortMethod` trace line properly output "alpha"? Your code seems fine. According to the documentation (https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html): "Local shared objects have some limitations that are important to consider as you design your application. Sometimes SWF files may not be allowed to write local shared objects, and sometimes the data stored in local shared objects can be deleted without your knowledge." Maybe your local settings don't allow SharedObjects to be written properly.

Comment: One more thing I thought of. If **SortObject.data.SortMethod** holds, for example, an empty **String** "", then it naturally won't pass **== null** condition thus never gets assigned anything else. I'd trace **typeof(SortObject.data.SortMethod)** and **getQualifiedClassName(SortObject.data.SortMethod)** just in case, and also **.length** if it turns out to be a **String**.

Comment: Another case: when you call `flush()` you need to check its result, if it happens to be "pending", you haven't flushed data into shared object properly!

Comment: 1. If I try to access it by tracing the .data from the SO or anything it returns nothing.

2. See #1. No.

3. I have tried running it at null or undefined as well for that check, to the same results. I have tried tracing it with all of those methods and it won't pull info, it won't even throw a null or undefined, the line just won't trace if I try to check the Object period. So I am assuming its some sort of issue somewhere with me not being able to create it.

Thanks for all the responses guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the event name .
The problem is in those lines below .

```
  var SortTypeSetting = event.target.name == "SortTypeSet";
  var ExtraSetting = event.target.name == "ExtraSet";
```

Try changing to :

```
  var SortTypeSetting = "SortTypeSet";
  var ExtraSetting = "ExtraSet";
```